# SQLiteDatabase add only if not already there

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I'm implementing a "add to favorite" function. Where the user should be able to add data to a database.

The DatabaseHandler is working and I've created a class to handle get/set methods.

I can easily add data to the database, but I can't quite figure out how to check if a specific id is already present and thereby not adding a duplicate to the database.

Here's my DatabaseHandler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "favoriteMovies";

// DataFavorites table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "movies";

// DataFavorites Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
private static final String KEY_RELEASEDATE = "releaseDate";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_DATAFAVORITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_URL + " TEXT,"+ KEY_RELEASEDATE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATAFAVORITES_TABLE);



}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}


// Adding new movie
public void addMovie(DataFavorites movie) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, movie.getId()); // movie id
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, movie.getTitle()); // movie title
    values.put(KEY_URL, movie.getUrl()); // movie url (poster)
    values.put(KEY_RELEASEDATE, movie.getReleaseDate()); // movie url (poster)

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}

// Getting single movie
public DataFavorites getMovie(int id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_URL, KEY_RELEASEDATE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    DataFavorites movie = new DataFavorites(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
    // return movie
    return movie;

}

// Getting All movie
public List<DataFavorites> getAllMovie() {

    List<DataFavorites> movieList = new ArrayList<DataFavorites>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            DataFavorites dataFavorites = new DataFavorites();

            dataFavorites.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            dataFavorites.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            dataFavorites.setUrl(cursor.getString(2));
            dataFavorites.setReleaseDate(cursor.getString(3));

            // Adding movie to list
            movieList.add(dataFavorites);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return movie list
    return movieList;

}

// Getting movie Count
public int getMoviesCount(){

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();

}

// Updating single movie
public int updateMovie(DataFavorites movie) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, movie.getId());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, movie.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_URL, movie.getUrl());
    values.put(KEY_RELEASEDATE, movie.getReleaseDate());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(movie.getId()) });

}

// Deleting single movie
public void deleteMovie(DataFavorites movie) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(movie.getId()) });
    db.close();

}
```

And here I want to add data if id doesn't already exist:

```
public void AddToFavorites(MenuItem item) {

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /* if ( id is not there ){

    // Inserting movie
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting movie..");
    db.addMovie(new DataFavorites(Integer.parseInt(Id), Title, Poster, Release));
} */

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `UNIQUE` index to the Table column to prevent duplicate entries. Also note that it will throw an Exception if duplicate is inserted, so don't forget to handle that

Comment: You need to make a query to check if the ID exists and if it does not exist enter.Also if your "id" is your primary key then not be repeated and you may want to put AUTOINCREMENT.

Answer (score 0):

you should use :

```
db.execSql("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO movies (columns names) VALUES (your values)");
```

or

```
db.execSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO movies (columns names) VALUES (your values)");
```

to insert the values, if they are already in the table they will not be added(first method) or they will be replaced(second method).